# Symfony access control allowing urlencoded slash in route name

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using symfony 3.4. I have a route in my security.yml file, more specifically in `access_control` key. The route goes something like this:

```
- { path: '^/route/subroute/SOME_TOKEN', roles: [ SOME_ROLE ] }
```

The `SOME_TOKEN` is a urlencoded string that may or may not contain  forward slashes in addition to an unknown number of other characters.

Judging by what the docs say [here](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/routing/slash_in_parameter.html#routing-slash-in-parameter) my route should look something like this:

```
- { path: '^/route/subroute/.+', roles: [ SOME_ROLE ] }
```

It gives me `404: Route not found.`. Do note that I'm using Apache2 with `AllowEncodedSlashes` option enabled.

My guess is that I simply don't know how to write the regex properly. Since I'm bad at regex too, that doesn't come as much of a surprise to me.

I've tried different variations of that. For example `(.+)`, `[.+]` etc.

```
# bin/console --env=dev debug:router | grep "/customer/unsubscribe/anon/"
  customer_communication_preferences_unsubscribe_anon           ANY        https    ANY    /customer/unsubscribe/anon/{hash}
```

Route definition:

```
customer_communication_preferences_unsubscribe_anon:
    path: /customer/unsubscribe/anon/{hash}
    defaults: { _controller: PizokelCustomerBundle:Communication:unsubscribeAnonCustomer }
    schemes: ['%routing.scheme.my_account%']
```

Comment: Your regex is perfectly valid. Please post entire `access_control` configuration. Also please tell what do you mean by `But ofc that doesn't work.` Do you get the `403 Forbidden`?

Comment: My bad, I've edited the question. I won't post the whole `access_control`, it's pretty big.

Comment: This is not related to the security then. Your routing configuration for the route is invalid.

Comment: it works fine without the encoded slash, so I doubt that that's the case.

Comment: 404 error is not related to the security. Your question is invalid. You asked for `Any pointing in the right direction is appreciated` and this is it: fix your webserver/routing configuration. Paste what `bin/console --env=prod debug:router | grep your_route` says. Please run `--env=prod cache:clear` before executing.

Comment: Post the route definition. Your first problem lies there, not on symfony security component.

Comment: Done and done. See edits.

Comment: Do as specified [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/slash_in_parameter.html) (and in both answers). Case solved.